# Low throughput with hazelcast queue as soon as multi-node cluster?

Tags: java, performance, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I use the test below to gauge my throughput times. When I run a local **one**-node cluster the throughput time is at around 90k messages/sec. As soon as I add another local node to the cluster, the throughput drops to ~5k messages/sec. Do I miss any crucial configs? I configured hazelcasts to skip data replication across nodes, so the speed should be the same, regardless of how many nodes, right?

I use Hazelcast 3.11 with the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation=
  "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.7.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="20">5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>localhost</member> 
        </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>

    <queue name="test">
        <statistics-enabled>false</statistics-enabled>
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <backup-count>0</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <empty-queue-ttl>-1</empty-queue-ttl>
    </queue>

</hazelcast>
```

Throughput test class:

```
package de.wipk.application.imdg;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IQueue;

public class HCTest {
  private static final int TOTAL = 1000000;
  private static final int LAP   = 100000;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    final IQueue<Object> queue = hz.getQueue("test");

    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastLap = start;

    Thread t = new Thread() {
      long lastLap = start;

      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLap) + " Start receiving msgs");
        for (int i = 1; i < TOTAL + 1; ++i) {
          try {
            Object msg = queue.take();

            if (i % LAP == 0) {
              final long lapTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLap;
              System.out.printf("<- messages %d/%d = %dms (%f msg/sec)\n", i, TOTAL, lapTime, ((float) LAP * 1000 / lapTime));
              lastLap = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    };
    t.start();

    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLap) + " Start sending msgs");
    for (int i = 1; i < TOTAL + 1; ++i) {
      queue.offer(i);

      if (i % LAP == 0) {
        final long lapTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLap;
        System.out.printf("-> messages %d/%d = %dms (%f msg/sec)\n", i, TOTAL, lapTime, ((float) LAP * 1000 / lapTime));
        lastLap = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
    }

    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " Finished sending msgs");

    t.join();

    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " Test finished");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a one-node cluster, this line

```
final IQueue<Object> queue = hz.getQueue("test");
```

gets you a reference to a queue in the current instance, essentially a local reference.

When more instances are added, the queue itself *might* be migrated to be hosted by another instance, so now the reference is to a remote queue.

There's a number of ways you could validate this. Probably the easiest would be to extend the time of the test, have the second node join partway through, and see if performance changes. You'd obviously only want the first process to do the `offer()`/`take()` actions.

If you want, add this

```
System.out.println(hz.getPartitionService().getPartition("test").getOwner());
```

to find where the queue lives as the other members join the cluster.

Comment: That's actually helped. On the first run, the owner was `null`. I expect that this means that the local member was the owner. On the second run, the remote member was the owner. I tested a simple 1000 entity write operation on a queue. On the second run, it took around 15sec (queue on remote member), which is 66 writer operation per second. Isn't that a bit low or ais IQueue#add simply a very slow operation? Are there better alternatives or is it a network problem?

Comment: "You'd obviously only want the first process to do the offer()/take() actions" ... How would I achieve that?

Comment: Slow network seems to be what your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613111/how-to-add-objects-to-a-distributed-queue-in-hazelcast-performantly

Comment: The owner should never be `null`. If you're sure you get that, log it as an issue on https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast with enough detail to prove how it occurs.

Comment: Use `hz.getCluster().getMembers().size()`. If it's 1 then do the `offer()`/`take()` and if it's more than one don't.